# fastest way to grab a frame from video saved into a sql database on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, video-capture

Currently, all my thumbnails image save to the path are from my desktop and here is my code

```
// browse and add thumbnail from computer
  private PictureBox GetThumbnailPictureBox(string path, int id)

        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        pic.Image = Image.FromFile(path);

        pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pic.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pic.Tag = id;
        pic.Click += new EventHandler(OnClickThumbnail);

        return pic;
    }
```

what should i do to extract a video frame so that i won't need to manual save a image?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Image.GetThumbnailImage`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Comment: can you show me an example to get the from a video using that method?

Comment: from your suggestion  using the Image.GetThumbnailImage. I am working on a Winform application.

Comment: I'm asking what software you are using to read the video stream.

Comment: i am not using any software to read the video stream. the video is stored in the database in my visual studio.